# Search arrays containing ranges which include the required value

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

How I can find arrays (or one array) where first and second values be between them?
I mean next:

```
arrays = [[0,453],[454,820],[821,1350]];
values = [320,519]
```

In this case we return:

```
[0,1] //320 =< [0,453] < 519 =< [454,820]
```

For values [30,450]:

```
[0,0] //30 =< [0,453] >= 450
```

Or [20,1200]:

```
[0,2] //20 =< [0,453] < 1200 > [454,820] < 1200 >= [821,1350]
```

I make an attempt write simple and fast algorithm but be confronted by difficulties (lack of knowledge)… and write it "as is"…:

```
//pseudocode
arrays = [[0,10074],[1075,1393],[1394,1418]]
values = [500,700]
for (i=0;i<arrays.length;i  ){
    if(arrays[i][0]<values[0]){ 
        first = i;
        if(arrays[i][1]>values[1]){
            second = i;
        } else if (arrays[i 1][1]>values[1]){
            second = i;
        }
        return [first, second]
    }
}
```

Is there best way for this question? Is it worth while to rewrite and complete pseudocode above?

---

@thefourtheye and @Tibos Im sorry - I cant choose best answer.

Answer thefourtheye - very fast solution, Tibos - really clean code.

Different goals - different best answers.

Comment: What should you return if the value isn't in any of the ranges? (-1? Null?)

Comment: This doesn't look right `arrays[i 1][1]>values[1]`

Comment: I don't think my solution is slow at all. Obviously there is room for improvement (like using a binary search through the ranges, for example), but it would increase complexity quite a bit. I made a jsPerf to test the speed of all the (working) solutions and suspciously enough mine appears to be the fastest. Please edit it if you spot a mistake. http://jsperf.com/rangefinder

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of functional methods on arrays. Here is how i would write the code:

```
var arrays = [[0,453],[454,820],[821,1350]];
var values = [320,519];

var result = values.map(function(value){
  for (var i = 0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
    if (arrays[i][0] > value) return null;    
    if (arrays[i][1] >= value) return i; 
  }
  return null;
});

console.log(result); // [0,1]
```

I returned null if the value isn't inside any of the ranges. Feel free to edit the code and return whatever value you wish for that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrays = [[0,453],[454,820],[821,1350]];
var values = [320,519];
// values = [30,450];
// values = [20,1200];

var start = -1, end = -1;
arrays.some(function(data, idx) {
    if (data[0] > values[1] || data[1] > values[1]) {
        end = idx;
        if (start === -1) start = 0;
        return true;
    } else if (start === -1 && (data[0] > values[0] || data[1] > values[0])) {
        start = idx;
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(start, end);
```